# Prefixing all broadcast channels when in dev environment in my Laravel app

Tags: laravel

I use Pusher with my Laravel app to notify of changes in real-time to web browsers to update pages accordingly.

I have 2 environments where (local & production) where events are broadcasted, I have found because both sites might be active and because they subscribe and push to the same channel names they cause undesired updates.

I was wondering if there is a way to prefix any broadcast channels with a value somehow? The alternative is that I go through each event and prefix the channel names (which is possible but I feel there could be a more "efficient" way).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using public channels then you check the environment using`app()->environment()`

And if it is using private channels then use uuid instead of id of the user.

it will return the value of APP_ENV from .env file

If it is local then you can prefix your channel name like shown below

```
Broadcast::channel((app()->environment() =='local' ? 'prefix-': '').'channel-{id}', 
function ($user,$id) 
     {return true}
);
```

Now you will do the same in EventClass in `broadcastAs` method

```
return new PrivateChannel((app()->environment() =='local' ? 'prefix-': '').'channel-'.$this->receiverId);
```

Now in production make sure you change APP_ENV=production and APP_ENV=local in your local development

Comment: In my original post I asked if this solution is something I could _avoid_, I do not want to prefix every Event class manually.

Comment: Didn't notice it. But this is the common way that I have found multiple best web apps are using e.g. Monday.com